# Buscador por medio de un URL

Tags: php

estoy realizando un buscador por URL, cuando le den al boton de buscar abra una URL y lo que yo coloque en el buscador complemente la URL al final, tengo esto

```
<form style="display: flex;width: 35%;margin: 0;padding: 0 1%;" action=http://www.terra-games.net/server_motd/pugs/player_stats.php?player_steamid=>
   <input style="width: 70%;border: 1px solid orange;background: #151515;padding: 2%;color: white;outline: none;box-shadow: 0;" type="searh" id="steamid_perfil" placeholder="STEAM_0:0:12345678">
<button style="background: orange;border: none;padding: 0 4%;font-weight: bold;color: black;-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 100px;-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;-moz-border-radius-topright: 100px;-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 100px;border-top-right-radius: 100px;border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;cursor: pointer;">
   <span style="font-family: 'icomoon' !important;speak: never;font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;font-variant: normal;text-transform: none;line-height: 1;-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;"></span>
</button>
</form>
```

perdon por el desorden, estaba haciendo algo apurado, en el action="" tengo la URL ya colocada pero lo que quiero es que lo que yo coloque en el buscador complemente el URl al final osea despues del ?player_steamid=AQUI agregar lo que yo coloque en el buscador, ¿como lo podria hacer funcionar?.

Comment: Pues usando correctamente el formulario con GET y un input con ese name (player_steamid) deberia bastarte (y un `target="_blank"` en el **form** para que se abra en una página nueva)

Comment: me podrias dar un ejemplo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como te he dicho en los comentarios, deberías hacer algo así:

```
<form target="_blank" action="http://www.terra-games.net/server_motd/pugs/player_stats.php" method="GET">
   <input type="search" name="player_steamid" id="steamid_perfil" placeholder="STEAM_0:0:12345678">
<button type="submit">
   <span></span>
</button>
</form>
```

donde usamos `target="_blank"` para abrir una nueva página, encerramos la URL entre comillas y le quitamos el `player_steamid=` porque se lo ponemos al input como `name`, le forzamos el metodo a **`GET`** y el boton lo hacemos del tipo `submit` para que ejecute el formulario.
He quitado todos los estilos porque no pintan demasiado para solucionar tu problema y he cambiado **type="searh"** por **type="search"** para dejarlo bien escrito.

Comment: Me funciono, muchas gracias